# Не открывается PDF по ссылке

Tags: html, href

Забабахал модуль, нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывался пдф в новой вкладке. У меня же он открывается только если нажать ПКМ на кнопку и открыть в новой вкладке, при простом нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.

В чем может быть проблема?

````
<a class="btn btn-primary white yellowButton link-modal" style="padding: 15px 50px; font-size: 1vmax;"
                            href="/upload/Catalog.pdf" target="_blank">Скачать<br> презентацию</a>```
````

Comment: не знаю, пригодится ли кому-то, но пришел к такому решению: ```<a class="btn btn-primary white yellowButton link-modal" style="padding: 15px 50px; font-size: 1vmax;" onClick="window.open('/upload/Catalog.pdf');">Скачать<br> презентацию</a>```